# Composer: Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring

Tags: 8, composer

When i remove drupal/pathauto or another module contrib composer print:
Dependency "drupal/core" is also a root requirement, but is not explicitly whitelisted. Ignoring.

Why ?

Answer (score 5):

`Composer remove` removes the selected package and its dependancies. However there are, some dependencies like `drupal/core` that shouldn't be removed. For example, if we try to remove `drupal/pathauto` this message would pop up, as `Drupal/pathauto` depends on `drupal/path` core module, and should/can not remove anything from core or any dependencies shared with other packages. You can see in `pathauto.info.yml` file what it depends on.